# Angular Material datepicker different formats in one component

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I would like to have two datepickers with different date formats in one component.

Unfortunatelly I spent three days already and I didn't achieve it.

I defined date format in core module by DateProvider and I know that I can override this formats in specific component, for example:

```
    export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
```

This solution would be enought when I want to have different formats between components, but how can I have two datepickers with different date formats in one component?

please help me!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?